# Принцип работы Jabber

Tags: сеть, php, передача-данных, c++

1) В [статьи](http://sgolovan.nes.ru/jabber/userguide/ar01s02.html) описано как работает клиент. Но не описано, каким образом устанавливаются соединения между Джульеттой и сервером, а также между сервером и Ромео.
Джульетта посылает сообщения на сервер. Как она это делает? Отрывает соединения через сокет, при этом на сервере ПОСТОЯННО работает еще один сокет на PHP, который принимает сообщения? или же Джульетта отправляет сообщения через запросы GET или POST, а сервер их обрабатывает на PHP, как сайт?
Сервер в свою очередь открывает соединения через сокет и отправляет сообщения Ромео?

Вообщем меня интересует, отправляется ли сообщения от Джульетты к серверу через POST/GET запросы или же на сервере постоянно работает сокет-слушатель?

2) И второй вопрос. Если сообщения Джульетта серверу может отправить, то как сервер отправит сообщения Ромео, если у Ромео динамический IP?

Comment: Откуда такая уверенность, что на сервере работает PHP?

Comment: @dzhioev а на чем? объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: классический jabber сервер ejabber написан на эрланге.

Для обмена сообщениями используется обычно tcp подключение.

> Если сообщения Джульетта серверу может отправить, то как сервер отправит сообщения Ромео, если у Ромео динамический IP?

что бы Ромео получил сообщение, он должен подключиться к серверу и установить соединение. Поэтому не важно, какой у него именно ip.

Comment: @KoVadim, грубо говоря. Ромео отправляет запрос на получения сообщения, а не сервер отправляет ему сообщения через сокет? Выходит,что Ромео должен постоянно отправлять запросы к серверу?

Comment: Ромео не нужно отправлять запрос. Сервер может спокойно послать ему сообщение в сокет.

Comment: @KoVadim, но как сервер узнает его IP. вдруг он изменился?

Comment: Если айпи поменялся, то соединение будет разорвано. Клиент будет вынужден переподключиться и аутентифицироваться.

Кстати, есть дока, которая описывает, как работать через http - http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0025.html и http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0124.html

Comment: @KoVadim теперь все стало яснее.

Comment: @huxi, никто не мешает конечно на PHP написать, но мне кажется для такой задачи лучше подойдет что-нибудь компилируемое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Используются сокеты или в крайнем случае comet-приложения(в случае web). Работа сокетов устроена таким образом, что после установления соединения сервер и клиент могут обмениваться сообщениями в двустороннем порядке, а не только по инициативе клиента (как при GET|POST).

2) Динамический IP адрес не меняется в течение сеанса интернет соединения, при разрыве связи выполняется повторная инициализация соединения с авторизацией и по новой пункт 1.

Comment: @huxi, ну можно сказать и так. Точнее все-таки пока активно текущее соединение с интернет провайдером, ваш IP будет оставаться постоянным. Оно изменится только при обрыве связи: выключите роутер, разорвете соединение, случится сбой у провайдера. Иногда провайдер искусственно рвет связь раз в сутки например, что бы этим не пользовались. Если бы это было не так, то даже простой файл не удалось бы скачать из сети)